# Keep rows if one column's values are not None while dropping duplicates in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a toy datafrme as follows:

```
id       type      name     purpose
1       retail    tower a    sell
        retail    tower a    rent
        office      t1       sell  
2       office      t1       rent
        retail      t2       sell
        retail      t2       rent
        retail      s1       sell
5       office      s1       rent
```

I want to drop duplicates based on subset columns `type` and `name`, instead of keep of `first` or `last` (`df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['type', 'name'], keep= 'last')`), I hope to keep the row if `id` column is not `None`.

The expected result will like this:

```
id       type      name     purpose
1       retail    tower a    sell
2       office      t1       rent
        retail      t2       rent
        retail      s1       sell
5       office      s1       rent
```

How could I do that in Python? Thanks.

Comment: there is `retail      t2       sell`, not correct should be `retail      t2       rent` ?

Comment: You're correct, if we use `last` instead of `first`, I changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper column by test nonmissing values, change order of rows by `iloc` and get indices by maximum values, it means last non misisng by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), last pass to `loc`:

```
idx = df.assign(tmp = df['id'].notna()).iloc[::-1].groupby(['type','name'])['tmp'].idxmax()
df = df.loc[idx.iloc[::-1]]
print (df)
    id    type     name purpose
0  1.0  retail  tower a    sell
3  2.0  office       t1    rent
5  NaN  retail       t2    rent
6  NaN  retail       s1    sell
7  5.0  office       s1    rent
```

If want keep first values:

```
idx = df.assign(tmp = df['id'].notna()).groupby(['type','name'], sort=False)['tmp'].idxmax()
df = df.loc[idx]
print (df)
    id    type     name purpose
0  1.0  retail  tower a    sell
3  2.0  office       t1    rent
4  NaN  retail       t2    sell
6  NaN  retail       s1    sell
7  5.0  office       s1    rent
```